# How to capture audio from phone microphone and convert it into Blob data for WebSocket transmission in Flutter Android app?

Tags: flutter, websocket

I am currently working on a Flutter Android app, and I have encountered a challenge. I need to capture audio from the phone's microphone and convert the audio data into Blob type data, which can be sent to the server via WebSocket.

I hope to achieve the effect.
The user starts speaking, transmitting audio data to the server in real time.

I tried to get the phone microphone audio data through flutter_webrtc, but I don't know what to do next.

```
_getUserMedia() async {
final Map<String, dynamic> mediaConstraints = {
  "audio": true,
  "video": false
};

try {
  MediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints).then((stream) async {
    _localStream = stream;
    RTCVideoRenderer render = RTCVideoRenderer();
    await render.initialize();
    render.srcObject = stream;
    localRenderer.value = render;
  });
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}}
```

Where do I listen to the user and get the audio data from the microphone?